# Is scalacheck non-deterministic approach problematic?

Tags: scalacheck

I know I can [make scalacheck tests deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639454/make-scalacheck-tests-deterministic), but I have a more general question: does the default non-deterministic behaviour of scalacheck cause practical problems? I've always thought that the tests should be deterministic and repeatable, and the other way around signals a bad tests design. Scalacheck seems to be used in a couple of "serious" projects, so I'm wondering whether breaking this deterministic principle is or is not in fact a real-life (not only theoretical) problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that "tests should be deterministic and repeatable" doesn't always apply. They obviously have their rather large place, but randomized testing is useful as well. In addition to QuickCheck/ScalaCheck and friends there are approaches such as [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing).

Comment: The link you provided says "So as to be able to reproduce errors, fuzzing software will often record the input data it produces" and it answers my question, thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, ScalaCheck in particular will print the arguments of any failing tests by default (of course, it will only work well if you have a sane `toString`).