# Reproducing a ScalaCheck test run

Tags: scalacheck

This was asked as a "bonus question" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639454/make-scalacheck-tests-deterministic, but not answered:

Is there a way to print out the random seed used by ScalaCheck, so that you can reproduce a specific test run?

There *is* a hacky way: wrap a random generator to print its seed on initialization and pass it to `Test.Parameters`. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, this is possible (see [scalacheck#263](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/pull/263)).
There are some nice examples here: [Simple example of using seeds with ScalaCheck for deterministic property-based testing](https://gist.github.com/non/aeef5824b3f681b9cfc141437b16b014).

In short, you can do:

```
propertyWithSeed("your property", Some("seed")) =
  forAll { ??? }
```

and the seed will be printed when this property fails.

Comment: doesn't work for other testing frameworks integrated with scalacheck, e.g. scalatest or munit

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this today. However, it will be implemented in the future, see https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/67

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57058280/5826349):

> **Bonus question**: Is there an official way to print out the random seed used by ScalaCheck, so that you can reproduce even a non-deterministic test run?

From `specs2-scalacheck` version `4.6.0` this is now a default behaviour:

Given the test file `HelloSpec`:

```scala
package example

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck

class HelloSpec extends Specification  with ScalaCheck {
package example

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck

class HelloSpec extends Specification  with ScalaCheck {
  s2"""
    a simple property       $ex1
  """

  def ex1 = prop((s: String) => s.reverse.reverse must_== "")
}
```

`build.sbt` config:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.0"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "specs2-scalacheck",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "4.6.0",
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2-matcher-extra" % "4.6.0",
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "4.6.0"
    ).map(_ % "test")
  )
```

When you run the test from the `sbt` console:

```
sbt:specs2-scalacheck> testOnly example.HelloSpec
```

You get the following output:

```
[info] HelloSpec
[error]     x a simple property
[error]  Falsified after 2 passed tests.
[error]  > ARG_0: "\u0000"
[error]  > ARG_0_ORIGINAL: "猹"
[error]  The seed is X5CS2sVlnffezQs-bN84NFokhAfmWS4kAg8_gJ6VFIP=
[error]  
[error]  > '' != '' (HelloSpec.scala:11)
[info] Total for specification HelloSpec
```

To reproduce that specific run (i.e with the same seed), you can take the `seed` from the output and pass it using the command line `scalacheck.seed`:

```
sbt:specs2-scalacheck>testOnly example.HelloSpec -- scalacheck.seed X5CS2sVlnffezQs-bN84NFokhAfmWS4kAg8_gJ6VFIP=
```

And this produces the same output as before.

You can also set the seed programmatically using `setSeed`:

```scala
def ex1 = prop((s: String) => s.reverse.reverse must_== "").setSeed("X5CS2sVlnffezQs-bN84NFokhAfmWS4kAg8_gJ6VFIP=")
```

Yet another way to provide the `Seed` is pass an implicit `Parameters` where the `seed` is set:

```scala
package example

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
import org.scalacheck.rng.Seed
import org.specs2.scalacheck.Parameters

class HelloSpec extends Specification  with ScalaCheck {

  s2"""
    a simple property       $ex1
  """

  implicit val params = Parameters(minTestsOk = 1000, seed = Seed.fromBase64("X5CS2sVlnffezQs-bN84NFokhAfmWS4kAg8_gJ6VFIP=").toOption)

  def ex1 = prop((s: String) => s.reverse.reverse must_== "")
}
```

[Here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.6.0/org.specs2.guide.UseScalaCheck.html) is the documentation about all those various ways.
This [blog](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/07/12/testing-in-the-wild.html) also talks about this.

Comment: can it be done w/o sbt? It is forbidden in many cases